# Merging pandas dataframes: How to figure out what is causing my error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge a couple of dataframes that I create from csv files, and it is failing on one of the files with the following error:

```
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Here is the code that I use for reading/merging:

```
df = pandas.io.parsers.read_table(myData, sep = delim, header = None, names = headers, index_col=False, converters = conv)
...
time_series = pandas.merge(time_series, next_df[id_fields + value_fields], on =
     id_fields, how = "outer", suffixes = ("_" + str(previous_time), "_" + str(this_time)))
```

By Googling the problem I got the suspicion that it might have to do with the uniqueness of the columns when trying to merge. I did see this problem in an instance where the tuple provided as suffixes to the merge function consisted of two identical entries. However, I have remedied that and am now getting the same error but for a different file. Now I have absolutely no idea what might be causing this. The indices on the data frames are just integers [0,1,2,3,4,...] so look fairly harmless.

Hence my question: Can I debug the merge function in pandas, and if so, how? I can't seem to find the source code (and I suspect it might not be written in Python anyway).

Or, if anyone has ever seen this error and could give me an idea what kind of problem this might indicate, please let me know. Unfortunately I can't post the files...

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: That's weird cos you can join/merge non-uniquely indexed on 0.11 (which pandas version are you using?) Can you give a small example where this doesn't work, e.g. does it fail with `df = df.head()` (or with just a couple of non unique index)

Comment: @Andy - I assume index always refers to the row names? Or are the column names an index as well? What does 'df = df.head()' do, and what makes you think that that should fail? I am using Pandas 0.11. Will try and see if I can reproduce the problem in a small example later...

Comment: actually you're right column names are also an Index (this could be the cause here..)

Comment: Thanks Andy, there was a problem with duplicate column names. It would be great if the error message was a bit more explicit though, e.g. saying which duplicate value in the index was causing issues...

Comment: a few years late, but there is now a link to the source in the online docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html